# CASE and NULLS issue

Tags: t-sql, null, case

I don't use CASE very often but have a pretty simple query I would like to return a generic statement for when the value is NULL.  I have written the below and do not get any errors but it doesn't catch the NULL values either.  I have shortened the list of articles as it is several thousand but was hoping someone could point out what I may be doing wrong.  Thank you in advance.

```
**USE Asag_Reporting

  GO 

SELECT DISTINCT ARTICLE_NUMBER,
                CASE PM_NAME
                WHEN NULL THEN 'No PM Available'
                ELSE PM_NAME
                END AS 'PM_NAME'
FROM   vw_GIM_Articles
WHERE  ARTICLE_NUMBER IN ('15110',
'19228',
'34563',
'36516');**
```

Comment: `case when PM_Name is NULL then 'No PM Available' else PM_Name end` should work. The trick, as always, is `is NULL` or `is not NULL`. `Coalesce`is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more thinking, I would prefer this over what I wrote below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ARTICLE_NUMBER,
                COALESCE(PM_NAME, 'No PM Available') AS [PM_NAME]
FROM   vw_GIM_Articles
WHERE  ARTICLE_NUMBER IN ('15110','19228','34563','36516');
```

---

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ARTICLE_NUMBER,
                CASE 
                WHEN PM_NAME IS NULL THEN 'No PM Available'
                ELSE PM_NAME
                END AS [PM_NAME]
FROM   vw_GIM_Articles
WHERE  ARTICLE_NUMBER IN ('15110',
'19228',
'34563',
'36516');
```

Comment: that worked perfect! - I did realize that using IFNULL in this scenario is much simpler but I am thinking forward to things that will be coming up and  I am curious if you could explain why the brackets make the difference here? I am assuming it denotes that this should be a column name versus a value in the column? Thanks again

Comment: I would suggest you use `COALESCE(PM_NAME,'No PM Avaliable') AS [PM_NAME]`.

Comment: @user3496218 The brackets is a method of Microsoft to indicate that the name is a name and should be treat altogether (in case they have blank space in the middle). This is only applied to Microsoft's T-SQL. ANSI standard is "", but if you use that, sometimes, you might run into some weird error with the QUOTED_IDENTIFIER stuff in SQL-Server (I saw it once, and did not understand it, still don't.). Check out more here: http://www.nigelpsammy.com/2014/03/significance-of-square-brackets-in-t.html